# htl5 voice recording with isualization

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm building a HTML5 software that records a voice and when playing that voice a visualizer should be in action.
Here is my code:

```
// variables
var leftchannel = [];
var rightchannel = [];
var recorder = null;
var recording = false;
var recordingLength = 0;
var volume = null;
var audioInput = null;
var sampleRate = 44100;
var audioContext = null;
var context = null;
var outputString;

if (!navigator.getUserMedia) navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.getUserMedia({
        audio: true
    }, success, function (e) {
        alert('Error capturing audio.');
    });
} else alert('getUserMedia not supported in this browser.');

// when pressing record

function getVal(value) {

    // if R is pressed, we start recording
    if (value == "record") {
        recording = true;
        // reset the buffers for the new recording
        leftchannel.length = rightchannel.length = 0;
        recordingLength = 0;
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "Recording now...";

        // if S is pressed, we stop the recording and package the WAV file
    } else if (value == "stop") {

        // we stop recording
        recording = false;
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "Building wav file...";

        // we flat the left and right channels down
        var leftBuffer = mergeBuffers(leftchannel, recordingLength);
        var rightBuffer = mergeBuffers(rightchannel, recordingLength);
        // we interleave both channels together
        var interleaved = interleave(leftBuffer, rightBuffer);


        var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(44 + interleaved.length * 2);
        var view = new DataView(buffer);

        // RIFF chunk descriptor
        writeUTFBytes(view, 0, 'RIFF');
        view.setUint32(4, 44 + interleaved.length * 2, true);
        writeUTFBytes(view, 8, 'WAVE');
        // FMT sub-chunk
        writeUTFBytes(view, 12, 'fmt ');
        view.setUint32(16, 16, true);
        view.setUint16(20, 1, true);
        // stereo (2 channels)
        view.setUint16(22, 2, true);
        view.setUint32(24, sampleRate, true);
        view.setUint32(28, sampleRate * 4, true);
        view.setUint16(32, 4, true);
        view.setUint16(34, 16, true);
        // data sub-chunk
        writeUTFBytes(view, 36, 'data');
        view.setUint32(40, interleaved.length * 2, true);


        var lng = interleaved.length;
        var index = 44;
        var volume = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < lng; i++) {
            view.setInt16(index, interleaved[i] * (0x7FFF * volume), true);
            index += 2;
        }


        var blob = new Blob([view], {
            type: 'audio/wav'
        });

        // let's save it locally

        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'Handing off the file now...';
        var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);

        var li = document.createElement('li');
        var au = document.createElement('audio');
        var hf = document.createElement('a');

        au.controls = true;
        au.src = url;
        hf.href = url;
        hf.download = 'audio_recording_' + new Date().getTime() + '.wav';
        hf.innerHTML = hf.download;
        li.appendChild(au);
        li.appendChild(hf);
        recordingList.appendChild(li);

    }
}


function success(e) {

    audioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    context = new audioContext();


    volume = context.createGain();

    // creates an audio node from the microphone incoming stream(source)
    source = context.createMediaStreamSource(e);

    // connect the stream(source) to the gain node
    source.connect(volume);


    var bufferSize = 2048;

    recorder = context.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, 2, 2);
    //node for the visualizer
    analyser = context.createAnalyser();
    analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.3;
    analyser.fftSize = 1024;

    analyser2 = context.createAnalyser();
    analyser2.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.0;
    analyser2.fftSize = 1024;

    splitter = context.createChannelSplitter();
    //when recording happens
    recorder.onaudioprocess = function (e) {
        if (!recording) return;
        var left = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
        var right = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(1);

        // get the average of the first channel, bincount is fftsize / 2
        var array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
        analyser.getByteFrequencyData(array);
        var average = getAverageVolume(array);

        // get the average for the second channel
        var array2 = new Uint8Array(analyser2.frequencyBinCount);
        analyser2.getByteFrequencyData(array2);
        var average2 = getAverageVolume(array2);
        // clear the current state
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 60, 130);

        // set the fill style
        ctx.fillStyle = gradient;

        // create the meters
        ctx.fillRect(0, 130 - average, 25, 130);
        ctx.fillRect(30, 130 - average2, 25, 130);
    }

    function getAverageVolume(array) {
        var values = 0;
        var average;

        var length = array.length;

        // get all the frequency amplitudes
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            values += array[i];
        }

        average = values / length;
        return average;
    }

    leftchannel.push(new Float32Array(left));
    rightchannel.push(new Float32Array(right));
    recordingLength += bufferSize;


}

// we connect the recorder(node to destination(speakers))
volume.connect(splitter);
splitter.connect(analyser, 0, 0);
splitter.connect(analyser2, 1, 0);
analyser.connect(recorder);
recorder.connect(context.destination);

function mergeBuffers(channelBuffer, recordingLength) {
    var result = new Float32Array(recordingLength);
    var offset = 0;
    var lng = channelBuffer.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < lng; i++) {
        var buffer = channelBuffer[i];
        result.set(buffer, offset);
        offset += buffer.length;
    }
    return result;
}

function interleave(leftChannel, rightChannel) {
    var length = leftChannel.length + rightChannel.length;
    var result = new Float32Array(length);

    var inputIndex = 0;

    for (var index = 0; index < length;) {
        result[index++] = leftChannel[inputIndex];
        result[index++] = rightChannel[inputIndex];
        inputIndex++;
    }
    return result;
}


function writeUTFBytes(view, offset, string) {
    var lng = string.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < lng; i++) {
        view.setUint8(offset + i, string.charCodeAt(i));
    }
}
```

My problem is that when running it's giving me an error :

```
cannot read property 'connect' of null in this statement:  volume.connect(splitter);
```

What is going wrong??

Comment: Please create a minimal example showing the problem, currently there is way too much code in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The creation of the volume gain node is done only after the success of getUserMedia, in the `success` function.

By the time the code encounter the `volume` connect command, `volume` is not yet allocated.

You have to 'chain' all your node connection starting from `success`.

Quick fix : just put those lines :

```
// we connect the recorder(node to destination(speakers))
volume.connect(splitter);
splitter.connect(analyser, 0, 0);
splitter.connect(analyser2, 1, 0);
analyser.connect(recorder);
recorder.connect(context.destination);
```

at the end of the `success` function.

Comment: can you please edit my code?I'm new to web audio API's.thank you in advance

Comment: No i can't, edits are meant to clarify the poster's intent, not to give an answer. See my Quick fix.

Comment: sorry not working.still same problem

Comment: mmm... no this can't be. You allocate volume at the start of success, so it can't be null at the end of it.

Comment: a new problem occured that left is not defined??can you help me with this as well please

Comment: i can't now. If you do a fiddle (www.jsfiddle.net) with clear comments, i'll have a look later.